# R "Floating point exception: 8" with caret and rbf

Tags: r, classification, r-caret

I was digging to learn how to use `caret::train` function with `rbf` method. I found this question, resolved with a basic R example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147529/what-are-the-best-r-packages-for-a-classification-problem-with-use-of-neural-net/147536#147536 (I'm copying the code below for convenience).

```
library(caret)

mod1 <- train(Species ~ ., 
    data = iris, 
    method = "nnet", 
    trControl = trainControl(method = "CV", number = 10))

mod2 <- train(Species ~ ., 
    data = iris, 
    method = "rbf", 
    trControl = trainControl(method = "CV", number = 10))
```

Yet, when I run that code on my Macbook, the first model builds fine, the second -- the one with `rbf` -- it just crashes R, raising a `Floating point exception: 8`.

I've tried other similar examples with `rbf`, using other datasets, but I'm always getting the same exception. What am I doing wrong???

Comment: The problem is not an issue with caret but with the underlying RSNNS package. If you run the rbf function from this package with the iris dataset you will get the same crash.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I was suspecting. I will try to contact the RSNNS package maintainer. For the sake of completeness, should others encounter the same issue, use `rbfDDA` instead of `rbf`. I got no crashes since the switch.